# Looking for a found footage time travel film

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I recall seeing a trailer for a film a while back, sometime in the last 2 years, and was wondering which film it was for.  I recall it being a found footage-style film, that centered on a group of teenagers using a time machine.  The trailer had some sort of party, I think it was a birthday party.  I recall the trailer ending with the camera showing one of the time traveling kids seeing themselves in a mirror, which I think was from the camera's point of view.  I think the twist was that this was at that person's birthday party, when they were younger, so it was a record that they'd traveled back in time.

Which film was this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### The film you are describing sounds like "[Project Almanac](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2436386/)" being released in 2015.

> IMDB describes it: A group of teens discover secret plans of a time machine, and construct one. However, things start to get out of control.